# web-proxy for angularjs application

Tags: angularjs, webproxy

I have to create a web-proxy script for my angularjs files because I got the error of CORS(Cross Origin Request Method) and I dont have any options to use Access Control Allow Origin because I cant make any changes to my server end.
My backend data is in java. So please someone tell me how to make a web-proxy for my angularjs application.

Or is there anyway to bypass the cors request from my browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick work around using foreach and json_decode.

If your print_r($json) comes in this format:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [studentid] => 5
            [firstame] => jagdjasgd
            [lastname] => kjdgakjd
            [gender] => 1
            [email] => dgahsdg@em.com
            [fathername] => hashsdh
            [mothername] => djhavshd
            [birthday] => 2016-03-21
            [address] => gafdhfadhs
            [tenth] => 45.235
            [twelfth] => 56.25
        )

)
```

This will do the trick:

```
 if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST')
 {
    $json = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"), true);
  //print_r($json);

    $data =array();//Open blank array for student data
    $num = array();//Open Blank array for number of student
    foreach($json as $k => $v):
        $num [] = $v; //number of student
        if(is_array($v)){
           foreach($v as $key=>$val):
             $data[$key] = $val;//Student data
           endforeach;
       }    
    endforeach;

$row= count($num);//Put number of student in $row    
for($i=1; $i<=$row; $i++){
     $q = 'INSERT INTO table (`col1`) 
           VALUES($data['studentid'])';//Looping through sql statement
}
```

Hope this will help.

Comment: giving this output



Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in C:\xampp\htdocs\so\test.php on line 20

Array
(
)


Notice:  Undefined offset: 0 in C:\xampp\htdocs\so\test.php on line 25

Comment: can you tell me $file is my json data which comes from post method.

Comment: Yes. $file is your data.

Comment: Pathik, I got no idea what is that thing

Comment: okay, let me try these guys, can you please check my whole  json object which I posted in my question,Mawia

Comment: guys, check this when I submit my form im getting the data inside the post like this.
JSON
 
0        Object { studentid="5",  firstame="jagdjasgd",  lastname="kjdgakjd",  more...}

Comment: what is that 0 guys after the json

Comment: json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"), true) in order to get associative array of your post data.

Comment: 0 may not be nessary any more any way.

Comment: What's the output of `print_r($json);` from my answer?

Comment: Since you have multiple student, you have to count the length of the array and loop your query.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/107950/discussion-between-ramansathiyanarayanan-and-mawia-hl).

Comment: mawia why are still make into another array $data.Please explain

Comment: @RamansathiyaNarayanan, Tell me what you have got with my answer. If it is not working. Then you tell me the errors.

Comment: I finished it. Thanks to you guys. Now Im trying to create a web proxy for my website so could you help

Comment: If this answer helps, please click the tick icon above.

Comment: ok, can you please tell me about making web-proxy for applications. I have updated the questin above

Answer (score 1):

User `json_decode` with `true` params

```
$data = "{"studentid":"5","firstame":"jagdjasgd","lastname":"kjdgakjd","email":"dgahsdg@em.com"}";
$d = json_decode($data,true); // true means it will result in aaray
print_r($d);
$stdId = $d['studentid'];
$fname = $d['firstname'];
$lname = $d['lastname'];
$mail = $d['email'];
```

**EDIT:**
For multiple json data:

```
$data = '[
    {
        "0": "1",
        "studentid": "1",
        "1": "David",
        "firstname": "David",
        "2": "Beckham",
        "lastname": "Beckham",
        "3": "1",
        "gender": "1",
        "4": "david123@gmail.com",
        "email": "david123@gmail.com",
        "5": "Beckham",
        "fathername": "Beckham",
        "6": "Beckhamii",
        "mothername": "Beckhamii",
        "7": "2016-03-13",
        "birthday": "2016-03-13",
        "8": "dgasdhghasd\nkajsdgjaksdh\nkahdgjaksgdas",
        "address": "dgasdhghasd\nkajsdgjaksdh\nkahdgjaksgdas",
        "9": "58.25",
        "tenth": "58.25",
        "10": "62.25",
        "twelfth": "62.25"
    },
    {
        "0": "3",
        "studentid": "3",
        "1": "Chris",
        "firstname": "Chris",
        "2": "Gayle",
        "lastname": "Gayle",
        "3": "1",
        "gender": "1",
        "4": "chrisgayle@email.com",
        "email": "chrisgayle@email.com",
        "5": "Chris Potters",
        "fathername": "Chris Potters",
        "6": "Christine",
        "mothername": "Christine",
        "7": "2016-04-20",
        "birthday": "2016-04-20",
        "8": "adhafsdh\njgadahksgdkjas\njagdjahsdlkajsld\nkajsgdjlahsdlkas",
        "address": "adhafsdh\njgadahksgdkjas\njagdjahsdlkajsld\nkajsgdjlahsdlkas",
        "9": "87.587",
        "tenth": "87.587",
        "10": "98.256",
        "twelfth": "98.256"
    },
    {
        "0": "5",
        "studentid": "5",
        "1": "jagdjasgd",
        "firstname": "jagdjasgd",
        "2": "kjdgakjd",
        "lastname": "kjdgakjd",
        "3": "1",
        "gender": "1",
        "4": "dgahsdg@em.com",
        "email": "dgahsdg@em.com",
        "5": "hashsdh",
        "fathername": "hashsdh",
        "6": "djhavshd",
        "mothername": "djhavshd",
        "7": "2016-03-21",
        "birthday": "2016-03-21",
        "8": "gafdhfadhs\nagdkjashdas\ndjkahsdklsaj",
        "address": "gafdhfadhs\nagdkjashdas\ndjkahsdklsaj",
        "9": "45.235",
        "tenth": "45.235",
        "10": "56.25",
        "twelfth": "56.25"
    }
]';

$json = json_decode($data, true);
echo '<pre>'; 
foreach ($json as $key => $value) {
    echo "StudentID: ".$value['studentid']."<br>";
}
```

**Output:**

```
StudentID: 1
StudentID: 3
StudentID: 5
```

Comment: what if I have got n number of studentid. How can I write that $data.

Comment: Okay, any example with this data because Im new to this line.
My form contains totally datas and when I click submit from my html page, these datas has to go to mysql database. Any example please

Comment: @RamansathiyaNarayanan give me sample data what you get in resopnse

Comment: @RamansathiyaNarayanan can you please cehck my updated answer

Comment: okay, so how can I put for my code instead of echo like $_POST or something

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/107948/discussion-between-pathik-vejani-and-ramansathiyanarayanan).

Answer (score 0):

Decode ur array like below..

```
$newarr= json_decode('urjsonstring');

extract($newarr);

$query="insert into stud values($studentid, $firstname,$lastname...)";
```